# How did the Marauders know about Hope in the Messiah Complex?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, messiah-complex

At the beginning of Messiah Complex, the Marauders are already on the scene when Hope is born.

Later on we find out that the Marauder's have access to Nimrod (the [robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimrod_(comics)), not Elmer Fudd) 'future tech'. When did they acquire this, and how does it help them?

How did the Marauders know about Hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not known how the Marauders knew about Hope, the mutant baby. Unlike as with the purifiers, and as far as I know, there is no prior Marvel X-Men universe issues or plotlines mentioning that the Marauders knew about the baby before the releasing of Messiah Complex. The Marauders simply knew about Hope because that came as a direct idea from the X-Office.

According to the writers and editors of the X-Office in their X-Men Summit Notes (printed in the Messiah Complex Hard Cover Edition-Nov. 2008), after their Messiah Complex creative retreat in New York on Jan. 2007, they came with few vague ideas and characters that they share to the readers as follows:

The event (X-Men: The Messiah Complex) was divided into three acts told across four titles (Uncanny X-Men, X-Men, New X-Men and X-Factor) over three months (Nov.'07-Dec.'07-Jan.'08).

In Act One they did set the stage of all the conflict, bringing the players onstage and defining four "camps" they all fit in. One of those 4 camps was the Bad Mutants: Bad guys who want to find the baby to control it. These bad mutants are the Marauders. Their goal: to control the baby.

[image]

Comment: Shame they don't have a more solid back story to it, but I don't think you could find a better resource to prove they don't!